# $2^E$ where $E$ is a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, automata

I'm studing the definition of automaton $G=(X, E, f, \Gamma, x_o, X_m)$ where $X$ is the set of states and $E$ is the set of events.

My sources report that $\Gamma:X \rightarrow 2^E$ is the indicator function of active events for a state. I guess it should return a set of events, but what is $2^E$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $2^E$ is ambiguous: it can mean the power set of $E$, i.e., the set of all subsets of $E$, though $\wp(E)$ is a more common notation for that. It can also mean the set of functions from the set $E$ to the set $2=\{0,1\}$.

Here it appears to be the latter. A function $h:E\to\{0,1\}$ is called the [indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the set $\{e\in E:h(e)=1\}$; there is a bijection between subsets of $E$ and indicator functions with domain $E$, so in practice the ambiguity of the notation $2^E$ is rarely very problematic. Note, though, that $\Gamma$ itself is not an indicator function: for each $x\in X$, $\Gamma(x)$ is apparently the indicator function of the set of events active for the state $x$. One could equally well define $\Gamma:X\to\wp(E)$ in such a way that $\Gamma(x)$ is the actual set of of events active for the state $x$, rather than the indicator function of that set; the two convey the same information.

Comment: And consequently, if you look at the indicator functions of an empty set with respect to several different domains, it ends up following that there exists one unique empty set with respect to a domain of discourse, but many empty sets across domains of discourse.

Comment: @Doug: No, it doesn’t. It follows that there is no such thing as **the** indicator function of a set: a set has an indicator function only as a subset of some set.

Comment: If the domain of discourse consists of {1, 2}, then the indicator function of a subset of {1, 2} which has no elements is {(1, 0}, (2, 0)}.  You implied that {(1, 0}, (2, 0)} conveys the same information as empty set.  If the domain of discourse consists of {1, 2, 3}, then the indicator function of a subset of {1, 2, 3} which has no elements is {(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)}.  You implied that {(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)} conveys the same information as empty set.  So "the empty set" comes as a local notion. Since {(1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)} and {(1, 0}, (2, 0)} are not the same, we have many empty sets.

Comment: @Doug: It does convey the same information **when one is considering subsets of a given set**, which is obviously the relevant context.

Comment: The indicator function does convey the same information when one is considering subsets of a given *non-empty* set.

Comment: @Doug: Or subsets of the empty set, though in that case it turns out, amusingly enough, that the subset and its indicator function are identical.

Comment: A function consists of a set of ordered pairs.  If the universe of discourse consists of {}, and the indicator function of {} is identical to {}, then please exhibit the relevant ordered pair here.

Comment: @Doug: $\varnothing$ is a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: An ordered pair has a first member and a second member.  {} has neither.  Though, I suppose as a definition, even if nonsensical, it might come as convenient to define {} as a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: @Doug: Your objection is beside the point: no one said that $\varnothing$ **is** an ordered pair. It is a **set** of ordered pairs.

Comment: If so, then exhibit the ordered pairs of which {} is a set, when {} is the universe of discourse.  Remember, {} is only a superset of itself.

Comment: @Doug: Obviously there are none. The fact remains that $\varnothing$ is a subset of $\varnothing\times\varnothing$ with the defining property of functions $f$ from $A$ to $B$: $$\forall x\in A\\forall y,z\in B\Big((\langle x,y\rangle\in f\land\langle x,z\rangle\in f)\to y=z\Big)\;,$$ with $f=A=B=\varnothing$. That makes $\varnothing$ a function from $\varnothing$ to $\varnothing$. And although I let you get away with it before, I will now point out that *domain of discourse* is not really the appropriate term here, since ground set whose subsets are of interest and which is the domain of ...

Comment: ... the indicator functions in question is certainly not the entire domain of discourse. I’m afraid that you have some very basic confusions that you would do well to clear up before you try to pick nits.

Comment: That only makes ∅ into a function if you accept that the definition still works when no x belongs to A.  It only makes ∅ into a function if you accept that if the antecedent here comes as false, then the quantified "→" statement will qualify as true.  The set of all indicator functions "contains" the domain of discourse.  You've agreed that the indicator function of the set gives the same information as the set.  So, if {1, 2} consists of the domain of discourse, then {(1, 1), (2, 1)} gives the same information as the domain of discourse.

Comment: @Doug: If you don’t accept such things, you’re doing your own private version of mathematics.

Comment: That only holds if I were the only person in the world thinking that way.

Answer (score 0):

$\Gamma$ indeed returns a set of elements of $E$, as $2^E$ is a notation for [power set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set), i.e. the set of all subsets of $E$.